# Snap throws error when trying to run 'code' (VSCode) or any other snap package

Tags: visual-studio-code, snapcraft, snap

Suddenly Snap has started throwing error when ever i try to run any app such as VSCode, Spotify and Bitwarden that is installed via snap, this was not the case until yesterday and the only notable change i have made to my system is that i have installed nerd-fonts for my terminal which i assume to not be of any problem here

---

Here are the commands i tried that have thrown this error -

```
foo@bar:~$ code
foo@bar:~$ spotify
foo@bar:~$ bitwarden
foo@bar:~$ snap run <app>
```

All these commands throw the same new error which was not the case until now -

```
/snap/snapd/17883/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: symbol lookup error: /snap/snapd/17883/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: undefined symbol: , version GLIBC_2.2.5
```

---

Here is my /var/log/syslog if it helps any -

```
foo@bar:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Dec  8 19:44:45 pop-os-darshit rtkit-daemon[1226]: message repeated 7 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
Dec  8 19:45:19 pop-os-darshit systemd[2407]: Started VTE child process 74376 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 67723.
Dec  8 19:45:21 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44347.768056] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:27 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44353.910138] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:31 pop-os-darshit gnome-shell[2622]: g_source_remove: assertion 'tag > 0' failed
Dec  8 19:45:33 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44359.851088] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:39 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44365.789843] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:45 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44371.937758] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:51 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44377.872728] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:45:57 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44383.811886] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:46:03 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44389.957269] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Dec  8 19:46:04 pop-os-darshit systemd[2407]: Started snap.code.code.6db8cb33-bf07-44a8-8db5-949e29732cd7.scope.
Dec  8 19:46:09 pop-os-darshit kernel: [44395.990775] IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
```

Line that is of particular interest in log

- `Dec  8 19:46:04 pop-os-darshit systemd[2407]: Started snap.code.code.6db8cb33-bf07-44a8-8db5-949e29732cd7.scope.`

I have tried to google this error but haven't found anyone having the exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me as well. I tried to reinstall go with Snap but it didn't work out. Also, it fails open vscode.

After a reboot, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Got a lot of similar issue on PopOS! 22.04 with:

- LXD
- Microk8s
- VScode

Tried to installed them from sources, nothing changed.

Update:
I tried to gather more informations:

`snap -vvv run juju`

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x563535c52d95]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main.func1()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:492 +0x95
panic(0x5635362f7840, 0x563536971900)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b6
main.run(0xc0003f3db8, 0xe)
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:559 +0x375
main.main()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/cmd/snap/main.go:497 +0x371
```

Another update:

After searching a bit more I found: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/solved-snap-refused-by-apparmor/20396

Maybe you have an issue with apparmor?